# Number of circles with equal radius around a point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, harmonic-analysis

Let $x_0$ be a point on the plane and $2^K$ be a large number. Given a family $\mathcal C$ of circles with equal radius $R$ satisfying the following property:

1. The distance $d_c$ of the centre of each circle $c$ to $x_0$ has $2^K R<d_c<2^{K+1}R$.
2. The circles have bounded overlap, that is, there is an absoulute constant $M$ such that for all $x$
   $$
   \sum_{c\in \mathcal C}1_{c}(x)\leq M.
   $$
   Then what can we say about the cardinality of $\mathcal C$, in terms of $K$?

Maybe it is easier to think of the case $M=1$ first. I came across this question when I am reading *A study guide for the l 2 decoupling theorem* by Bourgain and Demeter. It is one step for an inequality which they say it is easy to verify, but I found it looks like much deeper.

Comment: By the bounded overlap property, have I understood correctly that you mean that each point is contained in at most $M$ circles?

Comment: And *what* exactly do they say is easy to verify? Do you have an explicit upper bound that you are looking to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough upper bound on the cardinality of $\mathcal{C}$ comes from the fact that each circle $c\in\mathcal{C}$ covers an area of at least $\frac{\pi}{2}R^2-\varepsilon $ of the annulus
$$A:=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^2: 2^K R<x<2^{K+1}R\},$$
that its center must be inside, where $\varepsilon>0$ quickly tends to $0$ as $K$ tends to infinity. The area of the annulus equals $2^{2K}R^2\pi$ and the circles cover the annulus at most $M$ times, so there are at most
$$\frac{M2^{2K}R^2\pi}{\frac{\pi}{2}R^2-\varepsilon}\approx M2^{2K+1},$$
circles in $\mathcal{C}$, where I just waved the $\varepsilon$ away.

---

Covering the annulus by a radial grid of circles of radius $R$ yields a family $\mathcal{C}$ of cardinality at least $M2^{2K-2}$, which can even easily be improved a bit, but already shows that the upper bound above has the same order of magnitude as the actual mininum.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of using a measure-theoretic way of proving this as you did.